# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, database-connection

In my Ubuntu VM, I kept getting

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

---

## update

I have configured my database like this in my .env file

```
DB_HOST=45.55.88.57
DB_DATABASE=b-prod
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=*********
UNIX_SOCKET=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

It works perfectly.

---

But when I use

```
DB_HOST=45.55.88.57
DB_DATABASE=b-prod
DB_USERNAME=b <----------------------------------------------
DB_PASSWORD=*********
UNIX_SOCKET=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I didn't work.

What else I should look  into to prevent this ?

---

I have a feeling that I have the wrong password.

How do I test my database password ? DB_PASSWORD=********* ?

---

This is all user I have

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------+
| User             | Host        |
+------------------+-------------+
| root             | %           |
| root             | 127.0.0.1   |
| root             | 45.55.88.57 |
| root             | ::1         |
| root             | b       |
| b            | localhost   |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost   |
| root             | localhost   |
+------------------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Did you GRANT permissions? Once granted, did you FLUSH privileges?

Comment: Try to login directly to say `phpmyadmin` directly using your credentials. Also, your host is not in the error. Your host is `45.55.88.57` but your error reads `@localhost`. If you just changed your config, do `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @JayBlanchard : How can log-in to mysql with as root ? I tried `mysql -u root -p` I kept getting `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: How do I know my root mysql password guys ?

Comment: Usually you set your root password whilst installing mysql / your server. Default could be just root as username and an empty password. How did you setup this VM?

Comment: I can't even get in as root. I've tried to re-set my root password. For some reasons new changes doesn't to take effect. I aked separate question here = http://stackoverflow.com/q/42497385/4480164

Comment: In my case, I had to enclose .env values in double quotes like DB_PASSWORD="#$Er34]" because it contained complex characters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### The solution:

Sometimes when you change your .env, the configs don't refresh without clear cache or restarting the server.

The error message are:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The database are trying to get the information from the "cached" .env configuration, you should try:

`php artisan config:clear`

if not solve, restart your server.

#### [Edit] Another **NON RECOMMENDED** option:

- Go to your `config\database.php`
- remove the .env configuration

And set your own credentials

```
'mysql' => [
            'host' => '45.55.88.77',
            'database' => 'prod',
            'username' => 'forge',
            'password' => '*********',
        ],
```

Comment: I tried both `php artisan config:clear` and `service nginx restart` , refresh my site, and still the same = http://www.bunlongheng.com/

Comment: Try the edit section of my answer, it's not recommend, but we can test the .env with that

Comment: I tried that with root user work, but with my other user `bheng` doesn't work. I deleted my forge user.

Comment: I update my post with more info. Do I need to grant my bheng user for more permissions like my root to be able to get int ?

Comment: You are not receiving more the `forge@localhost` error, now you are receiving the `bheng@locahost` in your error, your .env was refreshed and is getting the username but not the host, try to check your host in your .env or change it manually on the `config/database.php`

Comment: Yes, you need to set the permissions to your user.

Comment: Can you please share me the instruction to do that for Laravel ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136799/discussion-between-joao-mantovani-and-ihue).

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful after I removed the configuration in the .env file the migration completed without errors. I just don't understand why it is working without this configuration? What's the difference with and without?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also faced this issue. ENV Variable should be with in the double quotes When we used complex characters of string on .env file. Such as passwords, secrets, key and so on.

```
DB_PASSWORD="FDXSCHVBGFFUOVIDVKTFUVIF++++++****"
```

please first check this scenario.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, trying to install Matomo on my localhost. I thought it was my MySQL configuration but it seems it was my adblockers and adtrackers plugins in my browser (Opera). Once deactivated, it worked fine.
I hope I could help...
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This file is caching some data like database configurations `\bootstrap\cache\config.php`. Either delete it or update it with new data.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with your database and not with laravel.

```sh
mysql> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------+
| User             | Host        |
+------------------+-------------+
| root             | %           |
| root             | 127.0.0.1   |
| root             | 45.55.88.57 |
| root             | ::1         |
| root             | b           |
| b                | localhost   | <-- must be % not localhost coz you want to access it remotely not locally
| debian-sys-maint | localhost   |
| root             | localhost   |
+------------------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hopefully this can help.

Answer (score 0):

check database port if you use wamp, login phpadmin and see **Server: MySQL** on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the "database user" has all the privileges of the database (and don't forget to import the SQL file).
2. Edit the Database credentials in **.env** file and make sure to add the quotes

   DB_DATABASE="dbname"

   DB_USERNAME="dbusername"

   DB_PASSWORD="dbpassword"
3. Run the following commands

   1. composer install
   2. php artisan config:clear
   3. php artisan cache:clear
4. Browse the URL : "http://localhost/Foldername/" or "http://yourdomain.com"
5. Done