# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

[image]**.env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=task
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=******
```

*List of all databases*
`mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| nodeDB             |
| performance_schema |
| phpmyadmin         |
| pythonDB           |
| sys                |
| task               |
+--------------------+
8 rows in set (0.13 sec)`

*Already tried these solutions*

> [SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496917/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-pass)
>
> [Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - No Privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges)

Comment: Have you created the Database `task` ? Also please check the username and password are correct and valid.

Comment: yes, I. already create task database using cmd.

Comment: Try getting into mysql with the username and password. 
`mysql -u root -p` and Enter Password. 
Check the credentials are actually valid.

Comment: Do your password has special characters? Try changing the password with a simple one and check whether the issue is with the password.

Comment: I am using ubuntu, I can enter using "sudo mysql" but fail to enter with "mysql -u root  -p"

Comment: Please check the password and username is correct. I think there may be some issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to login to mysql console. Then try printing the Mysql Users by the following commands.

```sql
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

If you find `root` has a plugin of type `auth_socket`, then either you need to change it to `mysql_native_password` by the following command.

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Do not forget to replace the `password` with your password.

Then Flush Privileges by using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Alternatively, you can create another user and grant privileges.

```sql
CREATE USER 'ankush'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ankush'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```